# Managing network address information

Tags: javascript, jquery, networking

I'm a developer at a networking company that really has no peers that work above me that I can use for any sort of sounding board for my code, so it's just me.  I was wondering if anyone would be willing to take a look at some of my code and just give me a few notes, bullet points, etc... on things that are wrong, things I should look into and so on.  If anyone is interested please feel free to comment.

I'm concerned with the JavaScript/jQuery.  It seems very coupled and I was wondering if there are any better ways to accomplish the things that I'm doing with this code.

Everything works, but I'm always sure there is room for improvement.

```
//Global networkInfo Object.  
var networkInfo = {};

$(function () {

    // Bind custom events

    $(networkInfo).bind('updateNetworkInfo', updateNetworkAddress);
    $(networkInfo).bind('updateNetworkRanges', updateNetworkRangeDropDowns);
    $(networkInfo).bind('selectNetworkRanges', selectNetworkRanges);

    // Set form validation

    $('form').validate({
        messages: {
            tbSiteName: "This is an invalid site code"
        }
    });
```

Add custom rule for site name.  This rule has been a pain because this is a webforms application and the name of the input can't be controlled.

```
    $('#tbSiteName').rules("add", {
        required: true,
        remote: function () {
            var r = {
                url: "/webservices/ipmws.asmx/SiteValid",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'tbSiteName': '" + $('#tbSiteName').val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return (JSON.parse(data)).d; }
            }
            return r;
        }
    });
```

`DrillDownProvisioning.aspx` doesn't allow the user to change the Subnet mask.  They should only be allowed to change this value by clicking on nodes in the `DrillDown Tree`.

```
    $('#ddSubnetMask').change(function (e) {
        $(this).val(networkInfo.SubnetMask);
        $('#lblMessageBox')
            .removeClass('hidden')
            .addClass('error')
            .text("Please do not change this value manually");
    });

    // Populate drop down with all the available vlans.

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/webservices/ipmws.asmx/GetVlans',
        data: '{}',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ddNumber').append($('<option />').val("").text(""));
            $.each(data.d, function (index) {
                $('#ddNumber').append($('<option />').val(this.VlanId).text(this.Number));
            });
        }
    });

    // When a vlan number is change auto populate the standard name and description input fields with the predefined values

    $('#ddNumber').change(function () {
        var number = $(this);
        var standardName = $('#tbStandName');
        var description = $('#tbDescription')
        if (number.val() === "") {
            standardName.val("");
            description.val("");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/webservices/ipmws.asmx/GetVlanInfo',
                data: "{'number': " + $('#ddNumber').val() + "}",
                success: function (data) {
                    standardName.val(data.d.StandardName);
                    description.val(data.d.StandardName);
                    standardName.valid();
                    description.valid();
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        }
    });

    // Populate drop down
    populateSubnetMask();

    // When the network type drop down is changed update the network ranges drop downs.

    $('#ddNetworkTypes').change(function () {
        $(networkInfo).trigger('selectNetworkRanges');
    });

    /*
    * toggle the 6 drop down menus.  If the check box is not marked
    * reset all the values to empty so they don't post.
    */
    $('#enableRange').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(networkInfo).trigger('selectNetworkRanges');
        } else {
            $('.mask').val(0);
        }
        $('#networkRangeSelectors').slideToggle();
    });

    /*
    * Open drill down tree for selection
    */
    $('.open').click(function () {
        $('#drilldowntreecontainer').toggle('1000');
        $(this).toggle();
    });

    // Close drill down tree
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('#drilldowntreecontainer').toggle('1000');
        $('.open').toggle();
    });
```

Because the page no longer posts back to itself the `document.referrer` should always be the previous page they visited from.  If for some reason a post back is required this will no longer work.

```
    $('#btnCancel').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace(document.referrer);
    });
});

/*
* Populate the dropdown box with the default
* range of 1 through 31
*/
function populateSubnetMask() {
    var dropDown = $('#ddSubnetMask');
    dropDown.append($('<option />').val("").text(""));
    for (var i = 31; i > 0; i--) {
        dropDown.append($('<option />').val(i).text("/" + i));
    }
}
```

Fetches the predefinied subnet start and stop values from webservice.  Populates select boxes with start to stop ranges to be selected.

```
function updateNetworkRangeDropDowns(e, network, bits) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/webservices/ipmws.asmx/GetNetworkRanges',
        data: "{'network': '" + network + "', 'bits': " + bits + "}",
        success: function (data) {
            networkInfo.networkRanges = data.d;
            var html = "<option value=''></option>";
            for (var i = data.d.Start; i < data.d.End; i++) {
                html += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
            }
            $(".mask").empty().append(html);
            $(networkInfo).trigger('selectNetworkRanges');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
}
```

Looks at the `networkInfo.networkRanges` object and selects the correct values in the drop down based on the values in the object.
Should only select values if the network type is a `VLAN(type=9)`.
Will reset all the values to empty if network type is not a `VLAN`.

```
function selectNetworkRanges() {
    if ($('#ddNetworkStart option').size() > 0 && $('#ddNetworkTypes').val() == 9) {
        $('#ddNetworkStart').val(this.networkRanges.NetworkStartSelected);
        $('#ddNetworkEnd').val(this.networkRanges.NetworkEndSelected);
        $('#ddFixedStart').val(this.networkRanges.FixedStartSelected);
        $('#ddFixedEnd').val(this.networkRanges.FixedEndSelected);
        $('#ddDHCPStart').val(this.networkRanges.DhcpStartSelected);
        $('#ddDHCPEnd').val(this.networkRanges.DhcpEndSelected);
    } else {
        $('.mask').val(0);
    }
}
```

Custom event that updates the values in the form inputs for `SubnetAddress`/`SubnetMask` with the values in the `networkInfo` object.
Because this function is bound as a custom event you can access the `networkInfo` object with `this`

```
function updateNetworkAddress() {
    $('#tbSubnetAddress').val(this.SubnetAddress);
    $('#ddSubnetMask').val(this.SubnetMask);
    $('#lblMessageBox').addClass('hidden');
    $('#tbSubnetAddress, #ddSubnetMask').valid();
}
```

This will only be required on the `drillDown` page, this gets the `subnet mask`/`address` from the `Radtree` on the left and inserts the values into the appropriate form `input`/`select`
This gets called by `DrillDownProvisioning.aspx` in the `Radtree`
`OnClientNodeClicked="drillDownNodeClick"`

```
function drillDownNodeClick(sender, eventArgs) {
    var node = eventArgs.get_node();
    var address = node.get_value().split("/");
    networkInfo.SubnetAddress = address[0];
    networkInfo.SubnetMask = address[1];
    $(networkInfo).trigger('updateNetworkInfo');
    $(networkInfo).trigger('updateNetworkRanges', [$('#tbSubnetAddress').val(), $('#ddSubnetMask').val()]);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks very clean and your naming convention is pretty good.  The only thing  I would prefer to do is to make the code object oriented by using functions as objects.  Otherwise, looking at the code without great networking knowledge, it looks very good.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Why put `populateSubnetMask` in to a JS function? I don't see any dependencies off-hand, so why not just hard-code the values? 2) That same control (ddSubnetMask), why not also just disable/readonly it?

Comment: @Brad Christie - 1.) Probably not necessary.  2.) I wasn't aware a select box could be set to readonly?  If I set it to disable it wouldn't post back the values when you submit the form.

Comment: @KyleRogers: Touché, didn't think about it being a submitted value. And you're right, can't be "readonly"  specifically, but more eluding to disabling the element. Everything looks good though from here, without having a live page to test how it plays out on. ;-)

Comment: @KyleRogers, did you ever find a cleaner way to write your code?  please post a self answer if you have.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From perusing your code a few times:

**Custom event abuse**

While it's very cool to have custom events, I would simply remove this extra layer of logic. It does not make sense to call `$(networkInfo).trigger('selectNetworkRanges');` if you could just call `selectNetworkRanges()`. I understand that you would loose access to `this` but you are accessing `networkInfo` directly in `updateNetworkRangeDropDowns` anyway.

**DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)**

- In `selectNetworkRanges` you could do `var ranges = this.networkRanges;` and then access `ranges` instead of `this.networkRanges` every time
- You are building a dropdown in `populateSubnetMask` and in `updateNetworkRangeDropDowns` in a different way even though the functionality is very close. With some deep thoughts you could create a helper function that could build a dropdown for both `#ddSubnetMask` and `.mask`
- `$('.open').click` and `$('.close').click` do the same really, you could just do this:

  ```
  $('.close,.open').click(function () {
      $('#drilldowntreecontainer').toggle('1000');
      $('.open').toggle();
  });
  ```

**What's in a name?**

- Please avoid short names like `r` , `d`
- It is considered good practice to prefix jQuery results with $ so `var $dropDown = $('#ddSubnetMask');` for example

**Style**

- Comma separated variables with a single `var` are considered better so

  ```
  var node = eventArgs.get_node(),
      address = node.get_value().split("/");
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  var node = eventArgs.get_node();
  var address = node.get_value().split("/");
  ```
- You are using both double quotes and single quotes for your string constants, you should stick single quote string constants. With the possible exception of your `data:` statements.

**Comments**

- Great commenting in general, maybe a tad too verbose at times
- You should mention in the top that this code relies on the jQuery Validation Plugin, in fact it would have saved time if you mentioned that in your question ;)

**Design**

- `ddSubnetMask` could be set as `disabled`, you would need a hidden input that contains the actual value to be submitted as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/368834/7602
- The last few functions starting with `populateSubnetMask` are not within your `$(function () {`, I would keep it all together

**Magic Numbers**

- You are commenting that VLAN(type=9), I would still advocate to create a `var IS_VLAN = 9` and then use that constant
- Not a magic number per se, `'application/json; charset=utf-8'` should be a properly named constant ( it's a DRY issue as well ).

**Dancing in the rain**

- Your `$.ajax` calls should deal with `error`, it will happen at some point

All in all, I could work with this code. You are correct that the code is tightly coupled. I think that's because of the data you have to work with, so I would not worry about it too much.